# is it necessary to have jenkins and openstack on the same system

Tags: jenkins, openstack

I am working on college project.which includes technologies Jenkins and Open-stack.I needed to create multiple instances in open stack using Jenkins.
so for that is it necessary to Jenkins and open stack present on the same system.

Answer (score 0):

nope, it is not necessary but you can use both though.